# Implicit Coercion of a value of a type of text.flash:TextField to an unrelated Int

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, textbox

Okay, so I'm trying to create a mobile flash game (I'm mostly an animator, a storyteller) and I'm having trouble with the input text for the player name. I've often read helpful tips on this site so I signed up to get some help. The code I use to load and save data is saveDataObject, But as far as I know input text has to be used with package code. I tried to convert it to function var, but then these errors occur. I am unsure how to use the Package class code, and everything I've read on it has been confusing. I am pretty much self taught for everything I know about code though tutorials and forums, so if it isn't explained in a way I can understand I wont be able to do it...

Here's the section of code if I wasn't clear(error lines separate):

```
var playerName:int;

init(); // this line goes directly beneath the variables

function f_1(init):void
{ // call once to set everything up

    saveDataObject = SharedObject.getLocal("DataBattle/character/name"); // give the save data a location
```

-

```
 playerName = txtPlayer;
```

-

```
    function addName(e:TouchEvent):void
    {

        var myTextBox1:TextField = new TextField(); 
        var txtPlayer:TextField = new TextField(); 
        var myText:String = "Cyan"; 

        function CaptureUserInput() 
        { 
            captureText(); 
        } 

        function captureText():void 
        { 
            myTextBox1.type = TextFieldType.INPUT; 
            myTextBox1.background = true; 
            addChild(myTextBox1); 
            myTextBox1.text = myText; 
            myTextBox1.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, textInputCapture); 
        } 

        function textInputCapture(event:TextEvent):void 
        { 
            var str:String = myTextBox1.text; 
            createOutputBox(str); 
        } 

        function createOutputBox(str:String):void 
        { 
            txtPlayer.background = false; 
            txtPlayer.x = 200; 
            addChild(txtPlayer); 
            txtPlayer.text = str; 
        }
```

-

```
        if(saveDataObject.data.characterName = playerName == null)
```

-

```
        { // checks if there is save data
            trace("No Player data yet."); // if there isn't any data on the computer...
            saveDataObject.data.characterName = playerName; // ...set the savedScore to 0
        }
        else 
        {
            trace("Player data found."); // if we did find data...
            loadData1(); // ...load the data
        }

        function loadData1():void
        {
            playerName = saveDataObject.data.characterName; // set the current score to the saved score
            trace("Data Loaded!");
        }
    } 
}

function saveData(e:TouchEvent):void
{
    saveDataObject.data.characterName = playerName; // set the saved score to the current score
    trace("Data Saved!");
    saveDataObject.flush(); // immediately save to the local drive
    trace(saveDataObject.size); // this will show the size of the save file, in bytes
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be nice to have some more details about this error. Like which line is actually throwing this error.

However even without it there are few things that looks weird right away.

```
var playerName:int;
// And few lines below
playerName = txtPlayer;
// Few more lines below
var txtPlayer:TextField = new TextField();
```

Looks like you're declaring `playerName` as int so you want to store numeric values, but then `txtPlayer` is a TextField. So by `playerName = txtPlayer;` you're trying to store TextField as Int value, which is not gonna work.

I can also see

```
if(saveDataObject.data.characterName = playerName == null)
```

and it's like :O
I'm not even sure how this part is being compiled. You want to do `playerName == null` check (which would return true/false) and then assign it to  saveDataObject.data.characterName ?

Comment: Okay, You just zoomed in on the exact two lines causing the errors, I'll edit the question after this to make it clear. Thank you, but now I have a follow up question or two. playerName was made from a modified code of a score keeping code, so that makes sense that its set for numbers. Whats the version of that code that would let me store playerName as a display value from the child output txtPlayer? And I'm not entirely sure were to put the assignment of  saveDataObject.data.characterName to playerName.

Comment: Ok, so **1st of all** I'd start with renaming the variables because it's super confusing right now. When I see `playerName` I expect it to be... um... Player Name? So if that's suppose to be a score I recommend naming it `playerScore` and now it's clear what it is and why it's an Int.

**2nd** remove `playerName = txtPlayer; `. I'm not sure what it's doing in there, but you set it up in `loadData1()` function anyway, right ?

Comment: 'playerName' is meant to be Player name, But I copy pasted a score code and modified it trying to make it a name code. I'll move 'playerName = txtPlayer;' to 'loadData1()' I need to be able to set up Player name as a name function, I guess I wasn't that clear... Sorry I do much better in person, thats why I usually read other people posts, but I couldn't find what I needed...

Comment: Update, I've done some research and changed the code signifigtly, so much so, this question no longer applies. (yet more issues still occur)

Comment: No worries, glad you have some progress. Good luck with more changes and you can always ask some more questions in here if you can't find the answers elsewhere. Also consider accepting answer if it was helpful or vote for closing the question if you feel it's obsolete.